# Closing a modal dialog in GMS 2.x and GMS 1.x?

Tags: dialog, version, dm-script

I have a dialog that needs 3 options, which I have implemented as buttons.  It would be best served by a modal dialog.  I have code like this:

```
class testDialog : uiframe
{
    void OnOne( object self )
    {
        Result( "Doing one\n" )
        self.close()
    }
    void OnTwo( object self )
    {
        Result( "Two.\n" )
        self.close()
    }
    void OnThree( object self )
    {
        Result( "Three.\n" )
        self.close()
    }
}

void ThreeButtonDialog(String description)
{
    TagGroup dialog_items
    TagGroup dialog_tags = DLGCreateDialog( "Test Dialog", dialog_items )
    dialog_items.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateLabel( description ).DLGAnchor( "North" ) ).dlgexternalpadding(5,5)
    TagGroup button_items
    TagGroup button_fields = DLGCreateGroup( button_items )
    DLGLayout( button_fields, DLGCreateTableLayout( 3, 1, 0 ) )
    TagGroup one_button = DLGCreatePushButton("Option1", "OnOne")
    TagGroup two_button = DLGCreatePushButton("Option2", "OnTwo")
    TagGroup three_button = DLGCreatePushButton("Option3", "OnThree")
    button_items.DLGAddElement(one_button)
    button_items.DLGAddElement(two_button)
    button_items.DLGAddElement(three_button)
    dialog_items.DLGAddElement( button_fields )

    Object dialog = alloc( testDialog ).init(dialog_tags)
    dialog.Display("Test...")
    DocumentWindow dialogwin=getdocumentwindow(0)
    WindowSetFrameposition(dialogwin, 300, 200)
}

ThreeButtonDialog("test")
```

This works fine in DM2.  In DM1, however, I get an error: script objects have no close method.

Instead, I thought I'd try to close the window.  Replace self.close above with:

```
DocumentWindow dialogwin=getdocumentwindow(0)
dialogwin.WindowClose(0)
```

This crashes both DM1 and DM2.  Is there a better way?  Do a modal dialog with radio buttons instead?

Comment: If a modal dialog would serve you best, why don't you just use a modal dialog? Same code as yours just using `pose()` instead of `display("Test...")`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but pose() adds OK and Cancel buttons.  I don't want those.  I want only the options (it's ambiguous what OK and Cancel mean).  Your radio code below is exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: No, you're right. I also couldn't think of a "pose()"ed dialog which doesn't have the additional OK/CANCEL. I just thought from your posting above that you didn't know how to pose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your goal is to have a modal 'choice' of multiple actions. A code which would do that would be

```
class CThreeButtonDialog:UIFrame
{
    TagGroup DLG,DLGitems
    TagGroup radio,radioItems

    object Init( object self, string title, string prompt, string s1, string s2, string s3 )
    {

        DLG = DLGCreateDialog(title,DLGitems)
        DLGitems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateLabel(prompt) )
        radio = DLGCreateRadioList( radioItems, 1 )
        radioItems.DLGAddRadioItem(s1,1)
        radioItems.DLGAddRadioItem(s2,2)
        radioItems.DLGAddRadioItem(s3,3)
        DLGitems.DLGAddElement(radio)
        return self.super.init(DLG)
    }

    number GetChoice( object self )
    {
        return radio.DLGGetValue()
    }
}


{
    object myChoice = Alloc(CThreeButtonDialog).Init("Choose","Chose your action","One","Two","Three")
    myChoice.Pose()
    OKDialog( "Chosen action:" + myChoice.GetChoice() )
}
```

[image: RadioDialog]

Answer (score 1):

For GMS 1.x the proper way to close a dialog from a UIframe would be to use

`self.GetFrameWindow().WindowClose(0)`
instead of 
`self.close(0)`
in your code above.

However, this will crash DM in GMS 2+.

The UIframe object's method `close( object self )` was added to the scripting language at some point during the GMS 2 development because of this issue. (Window management changed between GMS 1 and GMS 2.)

Answer (score 0):

If your main script is actually running on a background-thread, then there is also the option to use a signal and wait for that signal like in the following script:

```
// $BACKGROUND$
Class CModal3Options : UIFrame
{
    object waitSignal 
    TagGroup DLG,DLGitems
    number choice

    object Init(object self, string title, string prompt, string s1, string s2, string s3 )
    {
        choice = 0
        DLG = DLGCreateDialog(title,DLGitems)
        DLGitems.DLGAddElement( DLGCreateLabel(prompt) )
        TagGroup but1 = DLGCreatePushButton( s1, "Action1" );
        TagGroup but2 = DLGCreatePushButton( s2, "Action2" );
        TagGroup but3 = DLGCreatePushButton( s3, "Action3" );
        DLGitems.DLGAddElement( DLGGroupItems(but1,but2,but3).DLGTableLayout(3,1,0) )
        self.super.init(DLG)
        waitSignal = NewSignal(0)    
        return self
    }
    void Action1(object self) { choice=1;waitSignal.SetSignal(); }
    void Action2(object self) { choice=2;waitSignal.SetSignal(); }
    void Action3(object self) { choice=3;waitSignal.SetSignal(); }
    number GetChoice(object self) { return choice; }

    number PoseForTime(object self, number timeOutSec )
    {
        self.Display("Test")
        waitSignal.WaitOnSignal(timeOutSec,NULL)
        self.close()
        return choice
    }
}

{
    object dlg = Alloc(CModal3Options).Init("title","Prompt text","one","two","three")
    number choice = dlg.PoseForTime(2)

    if ( 0 == choice )
    {
        OKDialog("Timeout")
    }
    else
        OKDialog("Your choice: "+choice)
}
```